# c#, дырявые textBox

Tags: c#, textbox, sharpdevelop

пишу прогу в SharpDevelop и строю обычную нубскую форму с текстбоксами, кнопкой и лабелем, вроде как всё нормально потом после каких то движений по проге или это баг... в общем все textBox становятся дырявыми, то бишь видно рабочий стол через них, клацая по ним действительно как палец в дырку сунул,  в чём трабла?

Comment: Проект в студию!

Comment: Возможно вы у формы установили свойство `TransparencyKey` равное такому же цвету как фон текстбоксов. Проверьте.

Comment: player one 3, действительно с цветами какой то баг был :) пасиба.

Comment: Из вашего комментария не очевидно, угадал ли я с причиной, но позволю себе оформить как ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У формы есть свойство [`TransparencyKey`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.transparencykey(v=vs.110).aspx?query=textbox) в котором задается цвет. Всё что нарисовано на форме этим цветом, становится прозрачным. Данное свойство можно применять для различных спецэффектов. Например, для создания формы с фигурными границами.

В вашем случае, цвет заданный в `TransparencyKey` формы, совпал с фоновым цветом текстбоксов.